# Reset component data on click (Without $vm.forceUpdate())

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have the following data in an application form component.

```
 data() {
        return {

            manuallyEnterAddress: false,
            currentAddress: "",
            postcode: undefined,
            postcode2: undefined,
            address: {
                county: "",
                town: "",
                addressLine1: "",
                atAddressFrom: "",
                atAddressTo: ""
            },
     }
}
```

Once the application for is completed the data will look similar to the code below.

```
 data() {
        return {

            manuallyEnterAddress: true,
            currentAddress: "Some House",
            postcode: SK1MPS,
            postcode2: SK5N0Q,
            address: {
                county: "Cheshire",
                town: "Chester",
                addressLine1: "Random street",
                atAddressFrom: "01/01/91",
                atAddressTo: "01/01/2010"
            },
     }
}
```

When the form has been completed the user needs a way to reset the application form, returning the the first stepper, with blank fields.

Manually writing each field to reset would be horrific as there's at least ten times the data.

I've tried forceUpdate as shown below with no success.

```
        newApplication() {
           $vm.forceUpdate()
        }
```

Is there a way I could use the "newApplication" function to reset all of the data on the component?

Comment: Are you using vuex store in application?

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no need to re-render the vue Component, which is what `forceUpdate()` will be doing forcefully. I will suggest using an object for modeling your form, lets say, `formModel`. For Example:

*Template:*

```
    <form id="app" @submit="checkForm" method="post" novalidate="true">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" v-model="formModel.name">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" v-model="formModel.email">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <<ul>
        <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
    </ul>
```

***JS:***

```
   let app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            errors: [],
            formModel: {}
        },
        methods: {
            checkForm: function(e) {
                let self = this
                self.errors = []
                if (!self.formModel.name) {
                    self.errors.push("Name required.")
                }
                if (!self.formModel.email) {
                    self.errors.push("Email required.")
                } else if (!self.validEmail(self.formModel.email)) {
                    self.errors.push("Valid email required.")
                }
                if (!self.errors.length) {
                    self.initializeForm()
                };
                e.preventDefault()
            },
            validEmail: function(email) {
                let re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
                return re.test(email)
            },
            initializeForm(){
                self.formModel = {}
            }
        }
    });
```

In this manner no matter how many input elements you have in your component you will just need to set the main model object.